# Java tracking mouse movement

Tags: java, grid, awt, mouse, mouselistener

I was setting up an interactive grid, where the grid is made up of a number of tiles and when you click a tile it will change to a wall, so that the user can make a maze using the walls.

I managed to get everything working fine and now just want to optimize it. At the minute I have to click each tile individually to put a wall down however I want to be able to click and drag so that everything I move over whilst holding left click will turn into wall.

```
frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){
            Point xy = me.getPoint();
            xy.y -= 29;
            xy.x -= 6;
            for(int i = 1; i < numOfTiles - 1; i++){
                for(int j = 1; j < (numOfTiles - 1); j++){
                    if(grid[i][j].isClicked(xy) == true){
                        grid[i][j].changeTexture();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Above is the mouseListener that I'm currently using to track mouse clicks on the grid. Any idea how I would go about about it?

PS: I'm not particularly looking for the exact code on how to do it(although that would be helpful) but more of HOW to do it, then I can figure out the code myself.

Comment: [Simple Mouse Dragged example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/awt/event/a-simple-mouse-drag-example/) should point you in the right direction.  You need to override `mouseDragged()` from [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html#mouseDragged%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29).